# Is having a grayer background a bad thing?

Tags: color, background, contrast

With F9F9F9 background:

[image]

Original:

[image]

I thought my blog looked a little bit boring with a plain old white background, so I tried it with #F9F9F9 and #FCFCFC.

I'm not really sure whether I like it. Would you consider it a positive or a negative addition to my blog?

It is primarily text-based, and the background affects pretty much all parts of it - the pots as you can see are not in a separate area.

The only immediate drawback that I see, it that my screenshots and some other images usually have more visible white borders (as in the example above).

Comment: Positive or negative is a comparison to the original and you didn't show us the original. In general though I think light grays and dark grays even 10% and 90% are preferred to actual white and black. That's part my own opinion, and part what I was taught in design school.

Comment: @Ryan I've added the original, thanks for the suggestion. The problem here is that, as you can see, this color affects both the website *and* article backgrounds. If the article was in a separate container, which had a color of its own, I suppose I'd use a darker color for the website background, and white for the actual article, because the contrast is greater - but I'm not sure what should I do with a theme like this.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks as though the community is opposed to this, I'm not quite sure why. I think it meets our critique guidelines fairly well. As for myself, I prefer the gray background.

You should take a look at this question:

[Never use white?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/never-use-white)

I agree with Scott's answer there but at the same time I think for something as large as a background its better to have something off white. To me, and this could be because of what I was taught in design school, white can often look "unplanned." Unless the rest of the site is exceptionally well thought out and works with the white background then it just looks like you didn't consider the background at all. With your revision, though not markedly better, it shows you considered the background. To me that's an improvement.

That said you should go and fix the images. Whether its a border, transparent png, or some other means. Leaving the white around the images on your new background again shows a lack of consideration.

**The condensed version**

Its nearly impossible for someone to determine if you CHOSE white or LEFT it white. Picking anything besides white answers that question.

Comment: Thanks, this seems logical. I have now added a gray background, but my posts are in "cards" of sorts (they even drop a cool shadow). The only problem is that it makes the mobile version horrible, the text is to narrow, and my CSS skills are minimal...